# Component unmounts on prop change when passed as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which takes another component as prop like below,

```
  <WrapperComp
  isEnabled = { enabled }
  view = { (payload) => {
    return <Test { ...props } testProp= { payload} />;
  } } />
```

Here view prop is a component, everytime when props changes, it causes Test component to unmount and mount again. Is there any way to avoid this.

Wrapper component is simple component which displays View component, something like below

```
const WrapperComp = (
  {View}
) => {
  return <View payload={ 'some payload' } />;
};
```

Comment: can you add the code of the Test component

Comment: what's wrong if the component rerenders on prop change?

Comment: it dosent just re-render, it unmounts for every prop change

Answer (score 1):

I figured out why it was unmounting and mounting again, the issue here is i am passing function component as a prop whose reference is changing on every re-render so new component is passed every time wrapper rerender, one of the solution for this is to use "useCallback"

```
<WrapperComp
  isEnabled = { enabled }
  view = { useCallback((payload) => {
    return <Test { ...props } testProp= { payload} />;
  }, []) } />
```